# N Multi-disk zip archives not supported

Tags: php, laravel

i want to download file to zip using php zipArchive but i am getting this error
'N Multi-disk zip archives not supported'.

Answer (score 0):

`$file_names` is the array of files which you want to add in the zip

```
 function zipFile($file_names,$archive_file_name)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE )!==TRUE) {

    }

    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
    //  $zip->addFile($files,$files);
        $zip->addFromString(basename($files),  file_get_contents($files));
    }
    $zip->close();


}
```